# How to run VScode in sudo mode in WSL2?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

I was configuring the new Windows subsystem for Linux 2 developing environment. I have installed VSCode in Windows and WSL2 distribution of Ubuntu 18.04. I can open VSCode in Ubuntu(accessed through Windows Terminal) normally when logged as normal user, using command as follows:

```
simp1e@ZhuXian:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32$ code .
```

But when I add sudo command in the front, the error occurs as follows:

```
simp1e@ZhuXian:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32$ sudo code .
sudo: code: command not found
```

At first, the problem remains after I switched to root user. Later I found that the PATH of root user didn't contain VSCode. So I add the VSCode path to /etc/environment. After that root user can open VSCode normally, but `sudo code .` still have the problem.
What should I do? Is this still related to the PATH?

Comment: What are you trying to do? running `code` from WSL usually starts Window's vscode (on regular privilege). You would need WSL host to be on administrator mode and then `code` would be privileged (Windows-wise). What is the output of `which code`?

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Comment: I've answered this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58980356/vscode-in-wsl-how-to-sudo-a-root-file-so-i-can-edit-it/61984421#61984421 . This is probably a duplicate (Although technically you asked the question first)

Answer (score 7):

The answer here helped me: 
[VSCode in WSL: how to sudo a root file so I can edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58980356/vscode-in-wsl-how-to-sudo-a-root-file-so-i-can-edit-it/60052328#60052328)

For some reason starting as root vs logging in and then switching to root worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I think the Remote WSL extension pack is what you are looking for. Install that on your local (e.g. host) version of VS Code, and then from either the command pallet (Ctrl + Shift + p or F1) or from the "Open Remote Window" and select the "New WSL Window" option (screen shot below from command pallet).

[image]