# VSCode in WSL: how to sudo a root file so I can edit it

Tags: visual-studio-code, sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

WSL v.1 -- VSCode v1.40.1 (using 'Remote - WSL' extension 40.3)

**How to open a root-owned file for edit using sudo and VSCode? (without running as root)**

If I open a root file without `sudo`, I can't edit it (expected):
    $ code /etc/profile.d/custom-profile.sh
    $

[image]

But, if I try to `sudo code` the file, I get:

```
$ sudo code /etc/profile.d/custom-profile.sh
[sudo] password for xxxx:
sudo: code: command not found
```

Binarify's answer below shows that I can switch the default user to `root`, but I definitely don't want to be running as root, so I'm still looking for another solution.

Comment: Really surprised this doesn't have a clean solution yet...

Comment: Here is one solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65963974/12160919. In short, you need to modify the /etc/sudoers configure file.

Answer (score 33):

You can own the file you want to edit, then give it back the ownership afterwards

```
sudo chown myuser /path/to/file
code /path/to/file
sudo chown root /path/to/file
```

Comment: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /path/to/group`
worked for me

Answer (score 14):

Set environment variable:

```
export VISUAL="code -nw"
```

Then you can edit any file like this:

```
sudo -e file
```

It will automatically make a copy of file, and, when you close the editor, copy it back.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. `sudo -e file` just defaults to what I have for the EDITOR env var. Followed your steps exactly: https://i.imgur.com/BAQBAGC.jpg. Also tried adding full path to `code` and setting SUDO_EDITOR to `code` as well. I assume you actually tried this? I can't think of what might be different on my system; I'm on WSL 2.

Comment: You must use and argument "code -w". The documentation says the precedence is SUDO_EDITOR > VISUAL > EDITOR. I use it daily.

Comment: This works and IMO the best answer. Definitely needs more upvote

Comment: It's needed the edit sudoers secure_path option and needs to launch vscode on windows before I run sudo -e on WSL2 in my case.

Comment: This was working for me and just stopped. Do you have any idea what I could be doing wrong?  It keeps opening the default editor instead of vscode.

Answer (score 13):

I got the same error , i was not able to save any file in vscode after editing and it was resolved by the following command :

```
sudo chown -R <user-name> <directory-name>
```

It worked for me , Hope it works for you too.
Thank you

Comment: This will recursively change the ownership of the directory and not just the file. If this is done on say `/etc`, where you usually want to change configurations, this would cause issues down the line. I'm not saying this is wrong, but just be careful with this one

Answer (score 9):

Currently, the only way I was able to achieve this was to use [rmate](https://github.com/aurora/rmate).

#### 1. Install rmate on your WSL VM

```sh
sudo wget -O /usr/bin/rmate https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aurora/rmate/master/rmate
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/rmate
```

I'm using a Debian Buster WSL here, however you can replace `/usr/bin` with an appropriate folder in your $PATH depending on your OS or your preference.

#### 2. Install the Remote VS Code plugin

[image]

make sure the Extension is enabled on WSL: after adding the plugin.

Here is how I configured the remote VS Code plugin

`File -> Preferences -> Settings`

[image]

#### 3. Start the VSCode rmate server

Press F1 and run Search for the `Remote: Start Server` command.

[image]

#### 4. Edit your privileged files

Start your WSL instance and open a terminal. If you've done everything correctly you should be able to now edit your files with sudo priveledges in your editor, even if you are not the root user.

```
sudo rmate /etc/profile.d/custom-profile.sh
```

Answer (score 6):

input this in powershell and press 'Enter'

```
ubuntu config --default-user root
```

then you will login wsl with root user and you can do anything now

Comment: @Binarify Thanks, but I don't want to run as `root` by default. I'm really looking for some way to do the usual 'sudo x'.

Comment: not a good workaround

Comment: If you're not in ubuntu, can follow this: https://superuser.com/questions/1566022/how-to-set-default-user-for-manually-installed-wsl-distro (Method 1 seemed to work)

Answer (score 5):

## SSH in as root through VS Code

Don't know if this is the best approach but it worked for me. Note that this should only be used on files that only root has access to in the first place. I think saved files will be owned by root. Use this to quickly change some settings but not to write code that can done by regular user.

### 1. Install ssh-server on WSL

```bash
sudo apt install ssh
```

### 2. Allow remote login as root.

Edit or add `PermitRootLogin yes` inside `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

### 3. Restart ssh server

```bash
sudo systemctl restart ssh
```

### 4. Connect to WSL in VS Code

`Ctrl + Shift + P` -> `Remote SSH: Add new ssh host` -> `root@127.0.0.1`
accept all fingerprints and stuff and you're in as root. You should be able to do anything now.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to allow `root` SSH access to WSL.

Answer (score 5):

if you install Ubuntu from the Windows store the command you will need to run at a windows command prompt is

```
ubuntu config --default-user root
```

or

```
ubuntu1804 config --default-user root
```

or

```
ubuntu2004 config --default-user root
```

(Note: depending on which version you installed this could be ubuntu1804.exe or ubuntu2004.exe)

Restart LxssManager service

```
sc stop LxssManager
sc start LxssManager
```

Comment: Do we really want the default user to be root? :/

Answer (score 4):

If there is a possibility to upgrade from WSL version 1 to WSL version 2 then you might be able to use `setfacl`. I've just tested using WSL 1 too and there ACL's are sadly not supported.

Why use `setfacl` over `chown` and `chmod`? To preserve given `chown` and `chmod` Linux permissions (because you might have different folders with different contents for different services running under different system users) using for instance Ubuntu 20.04 (which runs using WSL2) and at the same time give yourself some access to open and edit files within a given WSL2 folder (or to edit just a specific file) you might be able to use `getfacl` and `setfacl`.

So you can try something like this to recursively (`-R`) modify (`-m`) permissions for `./path-to-folder` for user `$USER` to include read, write and execute (`rwx`) permissions.

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:$USER:rwx ./path-to-folder
cd ./path-to-folder
code .
```

Then you can go ahead and change some files within the folder from Visual Studio Code and `chown` and `chmod` permissions will stay the same.

Of course you can also use `setfacl` for changing the ACL permissions for an individual file.

I've tested this successfully using WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04. I don't know if every distribution supports ACL permissions by default. But Ubuntu 20.04 appears to have support for `getfacl` and `setfacl`.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the user to root doesn't seem like a good solution.
As Barafu Albino said, you need to set the `SUDO_EDITOR` environment variable.

- If you use VSCode for **Windows**

For me, the solution looks like this:

```
export VS_CODE="/mnt/c/Users/alex/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft\ VS\ Code/bin/code"
export SUDO_EDITOR="${VS_CODE} -nw"
```

You may use `$ which code` to find the VScode binary in Linux or `where code` in the Windows CMD. Make sure you don't forget to escaped the spaces in the resulting path.

- If you use the **Linux** version of VScode try this:

`export SUDO_EDITOR="code -nw"`

Finally, you can edit the files with `sudo -e /path/to/file.`

Comment: for those who use vscode ssh, you might want to avoid open vscode new window and change the path to vscode bin `which code` and update bin path `export SUDO_EDITOR="/home/admi/.vscode-server/bin/2cf817401dc/bin/remote-cli/code -w"`

Answer (score 0):

No need for `sudo -i` to be root user
add more details to the answer from @innomerphey :

```bash
which code
vi ~/.bashrc
```

Press `O` to add new line above the cursor, add Linux vscode `code -w` like this:

```
export SUDO_EDITOR="/home/admin/.vscode-server/bin/1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e/bin/remote-cli/code -w"
```

ps: **Replace hash value `1a5da...` in path**. Everytime you restart a SSH session, the `export` will expired. The permanent way is to update `/etc/environment`

then refresh env:

```bash
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now use `sudoedit`:

```
sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```