# Visual Studio Code is not working on WSL2

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I try open VS Code in WSL2 Terminal, like this:

```
code .
```

I get the following error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory {DIRECTORY} : Permission denied
```

When started with sudo:

```
sudo: code: command not found
```

I added VS Code to my PATH on Windows, and installed  [WSL-Remote](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl)

I am working on:

- Windows 10 Pro 10.0.19041
- WSL 2
- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- VS Code 1.47.1

Answer (score 4):

Check the configure file(`/etc/sudoers`), you need to modify the `secure_path` to enable run VS code with sudo command.

[image]

Also, it is better if you put the command path into /etc/profile, so every user could run `VS code`.

Comment: could we get this not as picture but as selectable text?

Comment: This is what worked for me: `secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/mnt/c/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin"`